# Registering user after successful Authorize.net DPM (Direct Post Method) payment

Tags: php, authorize.net

Is the following possible with the Authorize.net Direct-Post Method? If so, how would this be integrated? More of a high-level explanation would be helpful:

- Visitor needs to fill out name, e-mail, and password fields for a new account
- This user information is stored in the database only after successful payment to authorize.net

FYI I'm working with PHP here.

**Ruling out the following**

Since DPM creates its own form via `getCreditCardForm` and doesn't allow "personally identifying" information via Merchant-Defined fields, I don't see an easy way to put this on the same page.

I can't put the user sign up form after a successful payment, because I can't be 100% that they will fill it out (say they got disconnected).

**Possibility?**

I was thinking about possibly having the user form on page 1, storing the name/email/pass in SESSION variables, and going to page 2 with the payment form. After successful payment, the SESSION variables would be used to store the user in the database, and the session would be destroyed. I am wary about the insecurity of storing the password in the session, and other possible issues with that method.

Another possibility would be using the authorize.net fields for e-mail and name, to insert the user into the database, while automatically generating a password that is displayed or e-mailed to them. I dislike that idea.

Should I just use the AIM (advanced integration method) instead? I am going to try that now. DPM had already been set up, is why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've switched to using AIM instead. Using the sample code from here:  http://developer.authorize.net/resources/files/samplecode/php_aim.zip

I copied over the HTML/CSS of the form fields from the previous DPM getCreditCardForm, since the sample didn't come with example HTML. User registration and payment are now on the same form. Now I just have to put the $_POST data into the curl request, and check if it was successful before adding the user to the database. Not too hard of a switch.